# Does opting out of having my content used for improvement mean there are no other forms of data retention of my content by OpenAI?

Tags: data, gpt, api, privacy

Regarding the use of OpenAI API, [Terms of Use at OpenAI](https://openai.com/terms/) mentions:

> You can opt out of having Content used for improvement by contacting support@openai.com with your organization ID. Please note that in some cases this may limit the ability of our Services to better address your specific use case.

Does opting out of having my content used for improvement mean there are no other forms of data retention of my content by OpenAI?

Comment: This question seems very specific to how OpenAI works. I think it may be better to ask directly OpenAI themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does opting out of having my content used for improvement mean there are no other forms of data retention of my content by OpenAI?

Since March 1, by default, "OpenAI will not use data submitted by customers via our API to train or improve our models" (see longer quote below) and data is deleted within 30 days if using of the OpenAI API. No idea about https://beta.openai.com/playground.

From https://platform.openai.com/docs/data-usage-policies:

> Starting on March 1, 2023, we are making two changes to our data usage and retention policies:
>
> - OpenAI will not use data submitted by customers via our API to train or improve our models, unless you explicitly decide to share your data with us for this purpose. You can [opt-in to share data](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSevgtKyiSWIOj6CV6XWBHl1daPZSOcIWzcUYUXQ1xttjBgDpA/viewform).
> - Any data sent through the API will be retained for abuse and misuse monitoring purposes for a maximum of 30 days, after which it will be deleted (unless otherwise required by law).

More details:

> The OpenAI API processes user prompts and completions, as well as training data submitted to fine-tune models via the Files endpoint. We refer to this data as API data.
>
> By default, OpenAI will not use data submitted by customers via our API to train OpenAI models or improve OpenAI’s service offering. Data submitted by the user for fine-tuning will only be used to fine-tune the customer's model. However, OpenAI will allow users to opt-in to share their data to [improve model performance](https://help.openai.com/en/articles/5722486-how-your-data-is-used-to-improve-model-performance). [Sharing your data](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSevgtKyiSWIOj6CV6XWBHl1daPZSOcIWzcUYUXQ1xttjBgDpA/viewform) will ensure that future iterations of the model improve for your use cases. Data submitted to the API prior to March 1, 2023 (the effective date of this change) may have been used for improvements if the customer had not previously opted out of sharing data.
>
> OpenAI retains API data for 30 days for abuse and misuse monitoring purposes. A limited number of authorized OpenAI employees, as well as specialized third-party contractors that are subject to confidentiality and security obligations, can access this data solely to investigate and verify suspected abuse. Enterprise customers deploying use cases with low likelihood of misuse may request to not have API data stored at all, including for safety monitoring and prevention. OpenAI may still have content classifiers flag when data is suspected to contain platform abuse. Data submitted by the user through the Files endpoint, for instance to fine-tune a model, is retained until the user [deletes the file](https://platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference/files/delete).
>
> Note that this data policy does not apply to OpenAI's Non-API consumer services like [ChatGPT](https://chat.openai.com/) or [DALL·E Labs](https://labs.openai.com/). You can learn more about these policies in our [data usage for consumer services FAQ](https://help.openai.com/en/articles/7039943-data-usage-for-consumer-services-faq).

No idea before 2023-03-01, OpenAI never replied to my email.